# Passing model / var to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, partials

I'm trying to pass some information from my model to my partial but with no success.

My index looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <% @players.each do |player| %> 
    <%= render partial: "players", locals: { player: @players }%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

My partial looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 player">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="t">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><%= link_to player.name, player %></h3>
                    <p><%= "#{player.location}, #{player.age}" %></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Player Model:

```
has_one :team
```

Team Model:

```
has_many :players
```

Where am I failing?

Edit: I forgot to mention I'm getting this error: 
    `undefined method 'model_name' for Player::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<%= render @players %>
```

instead of

```
<% @players.each do |player| %> 
  <%= render partial: "players", locals: { player: @players }%>
<% end %>
```

or otherwise

replace `@players` with `player`

```
<%= render partial: "players", locals: { player: player }%>
```

Comment: `<%= render @players %>` rendered my collection 7 times.
`<%= render partial: "players", locals: { player: player }%>` rendered it once. I'll do some quick tests to see if it works.. Could you explain me why you don't use the @ ?

Comment: I didn't remove it... I should've ?

Comment: Without the each block it throws an undefined variable error in the partial.

Comment: you have to remove it when you use the first one (`render @players`) otherwise your partial will be rendered n-times.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `undefined method 'model_name' for Player::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class` errors because you pass a collection to the partial `locals: { player: @players }` `@players` here is the `ActiveRecord_Relation` collection. `link_to player.name, player` tried to make a path from collection and fails.

`index.html.erb` page:

```
<div class="row">
   <%= render partial: 'player', collection: @players %>
</div>
```

`_player.html.erb` partial:

```
<div class="col-md-2 player">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="t">
             <div class="caption">
                 <h3><%= link_to player.name, player %></h3>
                 <p><%= "#{player.location}, #{player.age}" %></p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the
>   individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the
>   collection being rendered **via a variable named after the partial**.

[**Layouts and Rendering in Rails**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections)

Answer (score 0):

When you are rendering your partial, pass to locals a record:

```
<div class="row">
    <% @players.each do |player| %> 
    <%= render partial: "players", locals: { player: player }%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```